# How to change icon of bottom navigation toolbar on loading previous fragment

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

How can i use `bottomNavigationView` when i click its moving perfectly but when i press back button fragment change to previous fragment but icon of `bottomNavigationView` not changed

```java
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;



        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_fav:
                selectedFragment = new Fragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_search:
                selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                break;
        }


        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        return true;
    }
};
```

It's change fragment when i click back but not icon so please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pages with **BpttomNavigation** and Fragments i suggest using **ViewPager**

> Benifits of **ViewPager** : flexibility, controllability, performance, cleaner code and nice swip animation on fragment change, and on finger swip.

in order to achieve your desired result, you can use something like this :

- put your ViewPager above the BpttomNavigation :

  ```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Doesn't need any addition -->
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
          android:layout_above="@id/bottomNavigation"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/viewPager"                           
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <!-- Set up menu and stuff -->
  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
          android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
  ```
- create your ViewPagerFragmentAdapter :

  ```
  public class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

  private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;

  public ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments) { 
      super(fragmentManager);
      this.fragments = fragments;
  }

  //Returns fragment by position
  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return fragments.get(position);
  }

  //Returns fragment count
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      return fragments.size();
  }
  }
  ```
- set up your views, fragments and adapter :

  ```
   @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      //Initialize views
      final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
      final BottomNavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation);

      //Initialize fragments list
      ArrayList fragmentsArray = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
      fragmentsArray.add(new FirstFragment());
      fragmentsArray.add(new SecondFragment());
      fragmentsArray.add(new ThirdFragment());

      //Initialize adapter and attach it to view pager
      ViewPagerFragmentAdapter adapterViewPager = new ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(
              getSupportFragmentManager(),
              fragmentsArray
              );

      viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
  }
  ```

**Your magic comes here, set up the listeners** :

- **ViewPager** page selection listener (swip or whatever) :

  ```
  viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onPageScrolled(int position, float v, int i1) { }

      @Override
      public void onPageSelected(int position) {
          //Here goes the magic
          switch (position) {
              case 0:
                  navigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.menu_first_fragment);
                  break;
              case 1:
                  navigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.menu_second_fragment);
                  break;
              case 2:
                  navigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.menu_third_fragment);
                  break;
              default:
                  //Handle exception
                  break;
          }
      }
      @Override
      public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) { }
  });
  ```
- **BottomNavigation** item selection listener :

  ```
  navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
          switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
              case R.id.menu_first_fragment:
                  viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                  break;
              case R.id.menu_second_fragment:
                  viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                  break;
              case R.id.menu_third_fragment:
                  viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                  break;
              default: return false;
                  break;
          }
          //I'm not sure if you should return true or false but you can try
          return true;
      }

  });
  ```
- **Finally**, to select the last fragment **onBackPressed()** you should keep it's position in a variable and call **viewPager.setCurrentItem(lastFragmentPosition);**, the listener will be automatically triggered, and sets **NavigationView** correct item,

  - you can check if **lastFragmentPostion** equales **viewPager.getCurrentItem();** to exit the activity or the app.

I haven't worked with java for a long time but i believe this code contains no errors.

> **Note** : You can initialize your fragments directly in your adapter in **getItem(position)** method if you want to return a new instance of the fragment every time this method is called, in this case you won't need the **ArrayList** in your constructor, don't forget to return the number of fragments in **getCount()** method

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

when you go back , try to do a `performClick()`

```
View view = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ACTION);
view.performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the selected Item like this,

```
BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_dashboard);
```

In case of back button pressing, you have keep track of the previous button id's for switching I think. In the viewpager, I think there's an automatic mechanism for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you do not use `addToBackStack(null)` in case of `BottomNavigationBar` and instead return to home fragment on `onBackPressed();`

For that, you can use

`FragmentManager manager;
 Fragment frag = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.your_frame_layout);`

and check the `instanceof` the object in `frag` variable

```
`if (frag instanceof HomeFragment) {
        super.onBackPressed();//Exits the app if home fragment
    } else {
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new HomeFragment()).commit();
//returns to home fragment when user presses back button
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);
    }`
```